# Show matplotlib plots from the list in PYQT5 layout

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt5

I have list of figures drew by using matplotlib.

```
# x, y1, y2, y3 array of points.    
list_of_plots = []
for i in range(0, 100, 1):
    x, y1, y2, y3 = get_points_array(i)

    fig = plt.figure(i)
    plt.plot(x, y1, '--rs', label='y1')
    plt.plot(x, y2, '-g*', label='y2')
    plt.plot(x, y3, ':bo', label='y3')

    list_of_plots.append(fig)
    plt.close()
```

With this code I got list of different plots.

```
print(list_of_plots)
```

> Figure size 640x480 with 1 Axes>, <Figure size 640x480 with 1 Axes>,<Figure size 640x480 with 1 Axes>, <Figure size 640x480 with 1 Axes>,<Figure size 640x480 with 1 Axes>, <Figure size 640x480 with 1 Axes>,...

And I have a GUI made by PyQT5. I want to show 3 specific plots inside the QHBoxLayout

```
self.second_row = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
#list_of_plots[0], list_of_plots[1], list_of_plots[2] will show inside second_row.
```

I have checked around Internet but I couldn't find any clue. I don't want to save figures as .png format then show on layout because accumulation of excess images can lead to a memory size shortage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use Qt's FigureCanvas provided by matplotlib, which is a QWidget that uses Figure for painting:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QWidget

import numpy as np

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


def get_points_array(i):
    x = np.arange(0, 2 * i + 10, 0.1)
    y1 = x * np.sin(x) * np.exp(-x)
    y2 = x * np.sin(x)
    y3 = x * np.cos(x)
    return x, y1, y2, y3


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        lay = QHBoxLayout(self)

        for i in range(3):
            x, y1, y2, y3 = get_points_array(i)
            canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure(figsize=(5, 3)))
            ax = canvas.figure.subplots()
            ax.plot(x, y1, "--rs", label="y1")
            ax.plot(x, y2, "-g*", label="y2")
            ax.plot(x, y3, ":bo", label="y3")

            lay.addWidget(canvas)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Widget()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I am looking for something like instead of directly draw and put into layout, firstly store all the plots (in this case list_of_plots holds all figures that already plotted) then put the layout from the list. In this way, I can update the visible page immediately without spending time to plot each time when it's refreshed.

Comment: @justRandomLearner I don't know where you got that *solution* from but it's impossible. I recommend you check how matplotlib works and how it is painted in Qt.

Comment: I see. I didn't get it from somewhere, it was what I think to overcome my issue but since I am new on PyQt5 it seems that it is wrong approach. Thanks for the advice. If you have any advice for make it effective to paint hundreds of plots of a single page and make those change when the button is clicked each time, you are welcomed! (:

Comment: @justRandomLearner You clearly have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: You are right. I didn't clearly explain my question but only my solution approach. Anyway, I have learned something from your advice. Thanks again for helping.